# ¿Alguna clase de ayuda para conectar con SQL Server en .Net?

Tags: vb.net

Hola comunidad de stackoverflow,

Quiero hacer un proyecto en Vb .Net que conecte con SQL Server, me han dicho que existen clases que me ayudan con eso y que contienen funciones para realizar llamadas a Procedimientos Almacenados o realizar operaciones directas como SELECT, INSERT o DELETE

He buscado, pero no logro dar con esas clases ! Supongo que esas clases tienen algún nombre especial pero no se cual es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las clases que debes utilizar para conectarte a `SQL Server` se llama `ADO.net`

[SQL Server y ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/kb9s9ks0(v=vs.110).aspx)

para trabajar con un `Stored Procedure` básicamente usarías:

```
Dim dt As DataTabla = New DataTable()
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connectionstring")

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("<storedprocedure>", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", valor)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

En este caso aplicaría para realizar un `select` ya que cargas un `datatable` con los registros que retorna, defines el nombre del `procedure`, asignas el `CommandType` del objeto `command` y defienes parámetros

Para realizar un `insert` o `update` sería:

```
Dim dt As DataTabla = New DataTable()
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connectionstring")

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("<storedprocedure>", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", valor)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

Es prácticamente igual sólo que lo ejecutas con el `ExecuteNonQuery()`